# Dynamically create in PHP a drop-down list from a range of numbers *with increments*

Tags: php, html, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I need to dynamically create in PHP a drop-down list of numerical choices like so:

```
<select>
<option value="120">120 cm</option>
<option value="121">121 cm</option>
<option value="122">122 cm</option>
<option value="123">123 cm</option>
<option value="etc...
</select>
```

I would like to only specify the starting and ending numbers.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
echo "<select>";
$range = range(120,130);
foreach ($range as $cm) {
  echo "<option value='$cm'>$cm cm</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

The [`range()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function can handle all of the situations you described in the comment.

```
range(30.5, 50.5, 0.5); // 30.5, 31, 31.5, 32, etc

range(30, 50, 2); // 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40 etc
```

Comment: Cool, never seen the range() function before. I had generally used a while loop for that scenario before.

Comment: This is really an issue of personal style, but there's nothing wrong with embedding the `range()` call directly in the `foreach`, like `foreach(range(120,130) as $cm) {`

Comment: Brilliant.
How about adding control over the increment, for example if the range was from 30.5 to 50.5 to make a list like so:
30.5
31
31.5
32
etc.

or setting the increment at "2" could yield:
30
32
34
etc.

Comment: As I said, brilliant! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Also:

```
echo "<select>";
for ($cm = 120; $cm <= 130; $cm++) echo "<option value='$cm'>$cm cm</option>";
echo "</select>";
```